# I found "Software" not "Software Center"?

Tags: 20.04, software-center

I am new to Ubuntu, I have installed it on VMware on windows 10 as a step before fully migrating to Linux. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and for some reason software center didn’t come with it.

I wrote `sudo apt update` on mu gnome terminal then `sudo apt-get install genome-terminal` which installed a software called “Software” which has a logo which looks like a blue suitcase.

I am not sure if this is a new version of software-center but review of famous software in it are very few so I think this isn’t the one I should be using, but is it?

writing `sudo apt-get install software-center`gets me an error saying `Package ‘software-center’ has no installation candidate` I am not sure what have I done wrong. Please help and thanks in advance.

Edit: I have also found more than one Vim (a text editor) to install, so I felt I was in the wrong place, is it normal to find 2 copies of the same software? Which shall I install? I couldn’t decide based on reviews as there weren’t much.

Comment: there is also sudo synaptic package manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canonical has decided to fork Gnome Software, tailoring it to promote its Snap package system.

As a result, it lacks support for Flatpak, and prioritizes the search for applications over Snap packages, which in my opinion generates some confusing cases, leading for example in some searches for pre-installed packages such as deb package to show a Snap package as the first result. and far below last, the pre-installed deb package. Unusual, in many cases even Ubuntu Software only finds the application in Snap.

Although Snap and Flatpak are for accessing certain applications and their versions, they are not an efficient replacement for most of the packages that make up a distribution, and particularly they are resources that I do not use because I estimate that they have a larger file size, a less integration with the desktop environment and a slower boot.

My suggestion is to install and use Gnome Software with the necessary plugins.

This requires:

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic gdebi gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-flatpak gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

You can also add the repository to manage Flatpak applications, running from the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I particularly prefer not to use anything from Flatpak or Snap, and I still use apt from the terminal, synaptic as GUI and in the case of independent deb packages gdebi, which resolves dependencies.

Comment: What is the purpose of the spaces in "ppa: alexlarsson / flatpak"? What is "gnome-software-plugin-flatp"? If you want to help people, then please make your answers fully reproducible and correct. It is not first time!

Comment: Thank you very much for your corrections. Knowing that someone closely monitors my posts, gives me peace of mind and allows me to correct my mistakes. Sometimes Cmu Sphinx is not so accurate.

Comment: @kyodake You recommend Synaptic. Is it still safe to use this? The [Synaptic homepage](https://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/index.html) has not been updated since 2009. I am not very familiar with Launchpad, but [the last trunk commit there](https://code.launchpad.net/~synaptic-developers/synaptic/trunk) appears to be in 2015. It looks as as though no one is maintaining it, which is worrying for something that can change all our packages.

Answer (score 0):

The "ubuntu software center" runs as program "software"

it looks like this on my installation (colors my be different)

[image: software center]

there aren't many reviews in the tool and discovery of software isn't ideal IMO

You can also get some software via the snapstore https://snapcraft.io/store

Discovery of programs is easier but you'll only have snaps while software center handles sofwtare that is in form of a snap or a normal "software package"(apt)

Answer (score 0):

You can just download and install apps using the new Software app. I have good experience with it in Lubuntu, and it isn't bad. But if it doesn't work, you can still go to the website where you would download it for Windows, and try using a .deb file to install your software. And it looks (for me) that it is a replacement for the old Ubuntu software